# Testing of data structures and xml in perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I have a tool that:
**1.** Converts several data structures to XML.  I use XML::Element to convert from data structure to XML.
**2.** Converts XML to data structures. I use XML::TreeBuilder to convert XML to data structures.

I need to write unit tests for this tool.
1. In order to test conversion of data structures to XML I perform testing of the XML using functions from Test::XML::XPath module.  For example - **like_xpath** function.
2. In order to test conversion of XML to data structures I use function **cmp_deeply** from Test::Deep.

Is it correct approach of testing data structures and XML?
Or I missed something?
PS.
It's my first experience of unit tests in perl.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm being simple-minded, but this seems like a situation where it might be better to test the big picture rather than worrying about the details in between. Here's a schematic example:

```
my $orig_data_structure = ...

my $xml = data_to_xml($orig_data_structure);
my $new_data_structure = xml_to_data($xml);

my $msg = 'The round trip should leave the data unchanged.';
cmp_deeply($new_data_structure, $orig_data_structure, $msg);
```

Comment: In this case we do not know what XML was generated. Yes - conversion is correct. But xml could be wrong.